# How to create a dynamic accordion?

Tags: wordpress, dynamic, accordion

Using wordpress and elementor pro.
1 column contains "accordion" widget and the second column contains "image" widget.
Each "accordion items" contains a title, description and an image.
I would like to hide the image of each "accordion items" and instead display them in the second column in the "image" widget. Is that possible ?
So when i have an active accordion, its corresponding image is displayed in the second column.
I do not have much experience in coding

I have tried using chatgpt to guide me through some steps but they did not work

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.